# Redirecting a user to google in django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

after the user has registered, they will be redirected to a html page containing ((We have sent a conformation email to your email address please `<a href="{% url '??' %}">confirm</a>` it to activate your account.)).
what should I replace ((?)) with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named url which you have mentioned in urls.py

```
<a href="{% url '??' %}">confirm</a>
```

If you have not  mentioned named url yet you can check how I have used `name` in below url.

```
path('email/confirm/', views.some_view, name='confirm_url'),
```

In above case your '??' should look as below.

```
<a href="{% url 'confirm_url' %}">confirm</a>
```

If you want to redirect to external url .

```
<a href="http://mail.google.com">website</a>
```

Comment: I know how to redirect users in my site address. in your example, the user gets redirected to mydomail/email/confirm/. I want him to be redirected to https://mail.google.com/